# How to change tab name on facebook

Tags: facebook

I'm creating a facebook tab application. It's added as a tab on a fan page. I want to change the tab name. I know how to set the tab name statically. I want to set it dynamically by any code like Static FBML.

Thanks.

Comment: I became convinced that Static FBML was created by facebook. It uses a special URL.

Answer (score 1):

fbml is deprecated
the tab label can be changed Page > Apps > scroll to the app > Edit Settings

Comment: Thank you. I could change tab label on new version of facebook page.